# Ajax-проверка select-формы и данных в БД

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, select, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Дело в следующем. 
У меня есть база данных с (пока что) двумя таблицами, допустим table1 и table2.
В каждой из них есть есть столбец "names", где содержится список названий.

А также на странице есть формы select, каждая из которых читает данные из своей таблицы:

```
$sql = "SELECT names FROM table1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "Table one: <select name='names'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['names'] ."'>" . $row['names'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select><br>";
```

И, соответственно, вторая такая же форма, которая читает список из второй таблицы.
Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы при выборе какого-то названия в одной из форм (допустим, в первой), шла проверка, есть ли такое же название в какой-то другой таблице (две таблицы со столбцами names, в которых список названий, чатсь из которых повторяются), и выводилось что-нибудь вроде "такое же название есть в *tablename*".

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Смотря для чего вы это делаете. 
вариант 1:

Открываете мануал по jQuery и ищите как получить значение выбранного <option>. Когда получили отправляем запрос на сервер и узнаем есть или нет такого названия.

Вариант 2:
Открываете мануал по jQuery и ищите как получить значение выбранного <option>.
Когда получили берем второй select и проходимся по всем options и узнаем значение каждого из них. Если есть совпадение выбранного option и option из второго селекта ругаемся.

И не забудьте сделать такую же процедуру, когда пользователь будет отсылать данные формы, на самом сервре.

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли не выводить те options которые есть в двух таблицах, если их нельзя выбирать?